# What is meant by a "projection operator" in the book "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information"?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, terminology-and-notation, projection-operator

I've started reading the book ["Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" by Michael A. Nielsen and Issac L. Chuang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107002176), specifically chapter 10 (about quantum error correction), and I'm finding myself a bit confused as to the notations used.

In page 435, above (10.15), I'd like to ask what exactly is meant by a "Projection Operator".
What does it project, and from where? Does it project a $2^n \times 2^n$ Hilbert space onto a $2^m \times 2^m$ Hilbert space (where, in the book example, $n=3$ and $m=1$)?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hi and welcome on Quantum Computing SE. Please post each question separately. A rule of this site is that each question should be laser-focussed on one topic.

Comment: My bad, thank you :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra) In quantum mechanics, we usually mean "orthogonal projection" if we say "projection" or "projector".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the projection operator projects from a $2^n$ dimensional Hilbert space onto an $m$-dimensional subspace of the same Hilbert space. So, if you were viewing it as a matrix, it would be a $2^n\times 2^n$ matrix of rank $m$ (with the special properties that $P^2=P$, $P=P^\dagger$ and $\text{Tr}(P)=m$, and others that are related).